# Listen to download event in ui-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-grid

I need to track the downloads of data in ui-grid. Is there a way I can listen to the download(CSV, pdf) events? I have gone through the api documentation but have not found anything. Tried to google but no luck there either.

Comment: Why not create your own download button that does what you need and then triggers the download data feature in the grid? Reference: [ui.grid.exporter Public API](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.exporter.api:PublicApi)

Comment: I was hoping to avoid doing that. I am using GridMenu.

Comment: Custom buttons can be added to the GridMenu. I've done this in the past and it worked well. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314536/how-to-customize-the-export-grid-menu-on-angular-ui-grid) is another SO post that talks about this....

Comment: Thank you guys, I am going to do it by creating the custom buttons. How about the buttons "Download selected" that appear automatically when there is a selection on the grid.